# Prove that $\forall x,y, \, \, x^2+y^2+1 \geq xy+x+y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Prove that  $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ the inequality  $x^2+y^2+1 \geq xy+x+y$ holds.

*Attempt*

First attempt: I was trying see the geometric meaning, but I´m fall.

Second attempt: Consider the equivalent inequality given by $x^2+y^2\geq (x+1)(y+1)$
and then compare $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \geq 2 $ and the equality $(1+\frac{1}{x}) (1+\frac{1}{y})\leq 2$ unfortunelly not is true the last inequality and hence I can´t conclude our first inequality.

Third attempt:comparing  $x^2+y^2$ and $(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2$ but unfortunelly I don´t get bound the term $2\sqrt{xy}$ with $xy$.

Any hint or advice of how I should think the problem was very useful.

Comment: Where is $z$ in the formula? Also for the second inequality, it should be $x^2+y^2+2\geq(x+1)(y+1)$.

Comment: Sorry is a typo

Comment: Find the minimum of the function $x^2 + y^2 + 1 - (xy + x + y)$ and prove that it is non-negative.

Comment: Instead of going for $(x+1)(y+1)$ you can subtract $2xy$ to get $(x-y) ^2\geq (x-1)(1-y)$ or $(a+b) ^2\geq ab$ for $a=x-1,b=1-y$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can rewrite $x^2+y^2+1 \geq xy+x+y \ $ as

$2x^2+2y^2+2 - 2xy - 2x - 2y \geq 0$

or as $(x-y)^2 + (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \geq 0$

which holds for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

Or start from $(x-y)^2 + (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \geq 0$ and expand to show that $x^2+y^2+1 \geq xy+x+y \ $.

Comment: Now you need to reverse the order of the implications.

Comment: Nice solution I never think in multiply by 2

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Sometimes I don’t understand why some people don’t accept the proof that goes: “$x^2+y^2+1 \geq xy+x+y$  $\Leftarrow 2x^2+2y^2+2 - 2xy - 2x - 2y \geq 0$ $\Leftarrow (x-y)^2 + (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \geq 0$, which holds for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$”. It’s logically correct, and saves you from having to copy the proof in reverse order again.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I am glad someone else has wondered about it too! I will remember that :)

Comment: @BenjaminWang It may not be possible for someone who encounters this question for the first time to think of this method.  Maybe this is what the people being are trying to say: You already knew the last expression beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

**First Solution**

By AM-GM inequality we have
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{2} \geq |xy| \geq xy \\
\frac{x^2+1}{2} \geq |x| \geq x \\
\frac{1+y^2}{2} \geq |y| \geq y \\
$$

Add them together.

**Second Solution:** By Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$
\left( xy+1\cdot x+y\cdot 1 \right)^2 \leq ( x^2+1^2+y^2)(y^2+x^2+1^2)
$$

Comment: Is really nice the first solution and the second I never think in use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Comment: IMHO, the factor two is too much, on the RHS, six times, in the AM-GM paragraph.

Comment: @Hanno ty fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the inequality as a quadratic inequality with respect to the variable $x$, then we have

$$x^2+y^2+1 \geq xy+x+y$$

$$\implies x^2+y^2+1 -xy-x-y≥0$$

$$\implies x^2-x(y+1)+(y^2-y+1)≥0$$

$$\implies \left( x -\frac{y+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)^2+y^2-y+1≥0$$

$$\implies \left( x -\frac{y+1}{2}\right)^2+ \frac 34 (y - 1)^2≥0.$$

- Equality occurs if and only if, when $y=1$ and $x=\dfrac{y+1}{2}=\dfrac 22=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1-(xy+x+y)$ notice that
$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=2x-y+1$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=2y-x+1$
then $\nabla f=0$ in $A=(-1,-1)$.

The function is convex since $f^{\prime \prime}(x,y)>0 $ hence the function have a minimum value in $1$ and then

$$f(x,y) \geq 1 >0 $$ and hence $$f(x,y)\geq 0$$

Comment: Do you mean convex instead of positive?

Comment: Yes, You are right

Answer (score 1):

Just to give yet another approach, observe that if we let $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$, then

$$\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+1\ge xy+x+y
&\iff(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2+1\ge(u+v)(u-v)+(u+v)+(u-v)\\
&\iff2u^2+2v^2+1\ge u^2-v^2+2u\\
&\iff u^2-2u+1+3v^2\ge0\\
&\iff(u-1)^2+3v^2\ge0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz or Buniakovsky inequality:  $(xy+x+y)^2 = (x\cdot y + 1\cdot x + y\cdot 1)^2 \le (x^2+1^2+y^2)(y^2+x^2+1^2) = (x^2+y^2+1)^2\implies xy+x+y \le x^2+y^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Look for perfect squares

$x^2 + y^2 + 1 \ge xy + x+y\iff $

$x^2 - 2xy+y^2 \ge -xy + x + y - 1\iff$

$(x-y)^2 \ge x+y - xy - 1$.

Now as the LHS is $\ge 0$ if we can show the RHS is $\le 0$ that be great.  If not... well we may hit an inspiration on the way.  We can always factor

$x+y - xy - 1 = x-xy + y-1 = x(1-y) + y-1) = x(1-y)-(1-y) = (x-1)(1-y)$.

Hmmm, no need for that to be negative but if it is positive then either $(x-1)$ and $1-y$ are both positive or both negative.

If both are positive then $x > 1$ and $y< 1$.  So $x-y > x-1$ and $x-y > 1-y$ and so $(x-y)(x-y) > (x-1)(1-y)$.

And if both are negative then $x < 1<y$ and so $(x-y)^2 = (y-x)^2$ and $y-x > y-1>0$ and $y-x > 1-x>0$ and $(y-x)^2 > (y-1)(1-x) = (x-1)(1-y)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
$$
\begin{align}
0
&\le\tfrac34((x-1)-(y-1))^2+\tfrac14((x-1)+(y-1))^2\\
&=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-(x-1)(y-1)\\
&=\left(x^2-2x+1\right)+\left(y^2-2y+1\right)-(xy-x-y+1)\\
&=\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)-(xy+x+y)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Motivation**

To prove $x^2+y^2+1\ge xy+x+y$, look at the difference
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)-(xy+x+y)
&=(x-y)^2+(x-1)(y-1)\tag1\\
&=(u-v)^2+uv\tag2\\[2pt]
&=(u-v)^2+\tfrac14\left((u+v)^2-(u-v)^2\right)\tag3\\
&=\tfrac34(u-v)^2+\tfrac14(u+v)^2\tag4\\
&=\tfrac34((x-1)-(y-1))^2+\tfrac14((x-1)+(y-1))^2\tag5\\
&\ge0\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: subtract $2xy+1$ from both sides of the minus sign
$(2)$: $u=x-1$ and $v=y-1$
$(3)$: $uv=\frac14\left((u+v)^2-(u-v)^2\right)$
$(4)$: combine terms
$(5)$: $u=x-1$ and $v=y-1$
$(6)$: sum of two non-negative numbers is non-negative

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x^2+y^2-xy-x-y$

$$\iff x^2-x(1+y)+y^2-y-z=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$ of the above quadratic equation

i.e., $$(1+y)^2\ge4(y^2-y-z)$$

$$\iff4z\ge3y^2-6y-1=3(y-1)^2-4\ge-4$$

$$\implies z\ge-1$$ the equality occurs if $y=1$ and $x=\dfrac{1+y}2=?$